# Pfaffian elements and anomalies

Tags: reference-request, spin-geometry, index-theory, dirac-operator

If $X$ is a compact even dimensional spin manifold, then we have a family of chiral Dirac operators parametrized by $Met(X)$, the (infinite dimensional) manifold of Riemannian metrics on $X$. This is considered, e.g., in Example 1.5 in [Determinants, Torsion, and Strings](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-107/issue-3/Determinants-torsion-and-strings/cmp/1104116145.full) by Dan Freed.

From other sources, e.g., Stolz and Teichner's [What is an elliptic object?](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eteichner/Papers/Oxford.pdf) I uderstand that for every Dirac operator $D_g$ in this family there should be a nonzero Pfaffian element $\xi_g$ in the Pfaffian line $Pf_g$ at the point $g$ of $Met(X)$. Possibly here one needs a lift of the spin structure to a string structure, as I seem to understand from Bunke's [String structures and trivialisations of a Pfaffian line bundle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0846.pdf). For $dim X=2$ which is the case I am mostly interested in, and that is the case considered by Stolz and Teichner,  there is no obstruction to the existence of this lift and the lift is unique up to homotopy, so we can safely omit this datum.

Something else I seem to understand is that, if $(f,\phi)$ is a spin diffeomorphism of $X$ (i.e., $f:X\to X$ is a diffeomorphism and $\phi$ is an isomorphism between the spin structure on $X$ and its pullback via $f$), then we have a distinguished linear isomorphism
$$
\Phi_{f,\phi}\colon Pf_g\to Pf_{f^*g}
$$
Since $Pf_g$ is trivialized by $\xi_g$ we'll have an equation of the form
$$
\Phi_{f,\phi}(\xi_g)=\alpha_{f,\phi,g}\xi_{f^*g}
$$
defining a 1-cocycle
$$
\alpha\colon Met(X)//Diff_{spin}(X)\to \mathbb{C}^\ast.
$$
This cocycle I think should be the anomaly of the Pfaffian element and should moreover be related to Liouville cocycle when $f^*g$ is conformally equivalent to $g$.

Despite all this seems to make good abstract nonsense, I have so far failed in finding a precise statement in the literature, so I'm asking the Oracle (the name I confidentially call MO)